# Configuring py.test in PyDev (Python 3, Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev, pytest

I have a Mac and have installed py.test to the Python 3 library (instead of Apple's standard Python 2.7 library). This is because I'm using Python 3.

When I run py.test in PyDev, however, the following error occurs. Any explanation on how to solve this? I've pondered this question for quite some time.

```
collected 1 items
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 96, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 130, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 745, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 339, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 334, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 614, in execute
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 139, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     return session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 592, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     config=self.config, items=items)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 745, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 339, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 334, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 614, in execute
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/mark.py", line 84, in pytest_collection_modifyitems
INTERNALERROR>     if not matchmark(colitem, matchexpr):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/mark.py", line 124, in matchmark
INTERNALERROR>     return eval(markexpr, {}, MarkMapping(colitem.keywords))
INTERNALERROR>   File "<string>", line 1
INTERNALERROR>     axfail=2
INTERNALERROR>           ^
INTERNALERROR> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's a picture:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxc6w.png)

*Notes:* I've installed PyDev bundled in LiClipse. I've configured the py.test test runner according to the documentation:

```
--maxfail=2 --tb=native
```

I then ran a simple py.test test file according to py.test's documentation:

```
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The pytest configuration seems correct.

So, some things to check:

1. Can you run it in the command line (out of LiClipse) with `py.test filename`?
2. How exactly are you running the tests? (Ctrl+F9 on that file or running a folder?)

The error seems to be when evaluating a mark in pytest (i.e.: pytest.mark.xxx), is it possible that you have some invalid mark in some other part of your project?

Comment: It does run correctly in the command line. I've been running Control+F9 (Command + F9 on the Mac).

Comment: Have you searched your marks in the project to see if some mark could be an issue? Also, do the following: create a module with: `import sys;print(sys.executable);print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))`, run from the command line and from the IDE and see if it matches.

Comment: When I run from the command line and from the IDE, it mostly matches. '/Users/UserName/Computer Programming/Python Liclipse Workspace/Practice/src' is and '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages' are two lines in the IDE but not the command line.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by project "marks" since I'm a bit new to PyDev. Do you have a link that explains this concept?

Comment: That's related to pytest, not pydev. You can see: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html for info on it.